# Fredholm integral equation

Tags: integral-equations

How can I solve the following fredholm integral equation
$$ψ(x)=x+λ\int_{0}^{2π}|x-t|ψ(t)dt$$ 
The kernel contains absolute value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First we express it in the form
\begin{align}
(I-\lambda K)\psi = x
\end{align}
where 
\begin{align}
K\psi(x):= \int_{0}^{2\pi} |x-t|\psi(t)\, \mathrm{d}t
\end{align}
Existence and uniqueness is guaranteed if $|\lambda| < \frac{1}{\left\|K\right\|}$, so assuming $K\colon C[0,2\pi] \to C[0,2\pi]$ we can estimate
\begin{align}
\left\|K\psi\right\|_{\infty} 
&\le \max_{x\in [0,2\pi]} \int_{0}^{2\pi} |x-t| \, \mathrm{d}t \left\|\psi\right\|_{\infty} \\
&= \max_{x\in [0,2\pi]} (2\pi^2 - 2 \pi x + x^2) \left\|\psi\right\|_{\infty} \\
&= 2\pi^{2}\left\|\psi\right\|_{\infty}
\end{align}
So assuming $\lambda \in \left(-\frac{1}{2\pi^{2}}, \frac{1}{2\pi^{2}}\right)$, we have convergence of the Neumann series
\begin{align}
(I-\lambda K)^{-1} = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \lambda^{i}K^{i}.
\end{align}
If $f(x):=x$, then
\begin{align}
\psi
&= \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \lambda^{i}K^{i}f \\
&= f + \lambda K[f] + \lambda^{2}K^{2}[f] + \cdots
\end{align}
Let's work out a couple of these integrals just for fun:
\begin{align}
K[f](x) &= \int_{0}^{2\pi} |x-t|t \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= \frac{1}{3} (8\pi^{3} -6\pi^2x + x^{3})
\end{align}
And:
\begin{align}
K^{2}[f](x) &= \int_{0}^{2\pi} |x-t|\left( \frac{1}{3} (8\pi^{3} -6\pi^2t + t^{3}) \right) \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&=
\frac{1}{3} \left(x^5-2 \pi  x^4-4 \pi ^2 x^3+20 \pi ^3 x^2-28 \pi ^4 x+16 \pi ^5\right)
\end{align}
To avoid pain in the ass, I calculated these terms via the following Mathematica code:

```
Assuming[x > 0 && x < 2 \[Pi] , Integrate[Abs[x - t]*t, {t, 0, 2*\[Pi]}]]
```

For $\lambda = \frac{1}{3\pi^{2}}$, the partial sums up to $\mathcal{O}(\lambda^{6})$ are shown below:[image: Partial Sums]

Comment: so what is the answer ?

Comment: @Syriamath: Dude!

Comment: I didn't see the solution

Comment: how can I use this code Assuming[x > 0 && x < 2 \[Pi] , Integrate[Abs[x - t]*t, {t, 0, 2*\[Pi]}]]

Comment: Don't wev have to use the 2- norm when we calculate $||K||$? Is it sufficient to calculate the infinity norm?